# Access to mysql database in the Server from client PC

Tags: mysql, networking, wifi, localhost, wampserver

I have a database in my **localhost**(Use WAMP server).I have created a **WiFi network** among several laptops.There is a **C# application** on client laptop which need to use the **database in server**(This application uses the data in the database).How do I do this?
(The client laptop can connect to my wamp server through browser successfully with address
**192.168.16.2**).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three things

1. Ensure that the application has the correct details to make the connection i.e username, password, database and hostname
2. Ensure that the server is using TCP/IP protocol (perhaps SSL) and that the firewall will not prevent incomming connections.
3. Ensure that the database user can connect from the remote machine. This can be achieved using the Workbench application.